# mysql 2 rows comparison in same table records

Tags: mysql, rows

I've searched the net corner to corner but haven't found a solution to my problem. I have a table called master which holds records of equipment with issues, When the equipment is first recorded in the database the status of the job is cat_id = 11, when someone repaired it they enter the same information again and change the status as cat_id = 1 or 2 or 3 etc . When the cat_id (status) changed to something else other then cat_id = 11 I want this job with that "mo_number" AND cat_id = something else to not to show up in the select query.

table: master

```
id   mo_number   part_number   cat_id       date_created   user_id
15    7200023         347893        11      01/03/2016     1
33    7200023         347893        1       10/03/2016     5
34    7200045         457890        11      11/03/2016     1

expected :
id   mo_number   part_number   cat_id       date_created   user_id
34    7200045         457890        11      11/03/2016     1
```

Here is my complete select query:

```
SELECT m.comment_id, m.mo_number, m.part_number, m.serial_number, m.comment,
       m.date_created, CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) as name
       FROM master AS m
         INNER JOIN users as u ON u.user_id = m.user_id
          INNER JOIN category as c ON m.cat_id = c.cat_id
       WHERE u.user_id = '1' AND m.cat_id = '11'
    ORDER BY m.mo_number DESC
```

I don't know how to write the query so that this job does not show up in the table as still open. I would appreciate if someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5afac/3)

**MySQL 5.5 Schema Setup**:

```
create table users (user_id int, first_name varchar(100), last_name nvarchar(100));
insert users (user_id, first_name, last_name)
select 1, 'John', 'Smith'
union
select 5, 'Neo', 'Anderson'
;

create table category (cat_id int, name varchar(100));
insert category (cat_id, name)
select 1, 'closed'
union
select 2, 'not so closed but not open too :)'
union
select 11, 'open'
;

create table master (
  id int, mo_number varchar(10), part_number varchar(10), serial_number varchar(10),
  cat_id int,  date_created date, user_id int, comment varchar(100));

insert master (id, mo_number, part_number, serial_number, cat_id, date_created, user_id, comment)
select 15, '7200023', '347893', 'SN00001', 11, '2016-03-01', 1, 'seems we can do it'
union
select 33, '7200023', '347893', 'SN00001', 1, '2016-03-10', 5, 'tested by Morpheus'
union
select 34, '7200045', '457890', 'SN00002', 11, '2016-03-11', 1, 'again that Miss drop it to bath '
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT m.mo_number, m.part_number, m.serial_number, m.comment,
  m.date_created, CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) as name
FROM master AS m
  INNER JOIN users as u ON u.user_id = m.user_id
  INNER JOIN category as c ON m.cat_id = c.cat_id
WHERE m.cat_id = 11 and not exists(
  select 1 from master as m1 
  where m1.cat_id <> 11 
    and m1.date_created > m.date_created 
    and m1.mo_number = m.mo_number)
ORDER BY m.mo_number DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5afac/3/0)**:

```
| mo_number | part_number | serial_number |                          comment |            date_created |       name |
|-----------|-------------|---------------|----------------------------------|-------------------------|------------|
|   7200045 |      457890 |       SN00002 | again that Miss drop it to bath  | March, 11 2016 00:00:00 | John Smith |
```

Comment: Thank you shibormat for your reply, I've edited the main post to show you the actual select query I have. Because I have inner join and I've tried to adapt your query in to mine but it did not work. So I am posting my whole select query.

Comment: just add to you where `and not exists(select 1 from master as m1 where m1.user_id = '1' and m1.cat_id = 1 and m1.date > m.date and m1.part_number = m.part_number)`

Comment: Hi Shibormot, I've updated my question, I think I wasnt clear in the first place, please analyse it again and provide me a solution. I would humbly appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks shibormot, I get an mysql syntax error using this query?